# React sidebar covering whole width

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am using the following Sidebar in my project

https://reactjsexample.com/minimal-side-navigation-component-for-react/

but if I made the component and import it to my page it spans across the whole page and the rest of the content goes underneath it. I have both of these ways:

```
return (
        <>
            <Sidebar />
            <Router>
                    <Redirect path='/user-portal' to='/user-portal/dashboard' exact />
                    <Route path='/user-portal/Dashboard' component={Dashboard} exact />
            </Router>
        </>
    )
```

and

```
return (
        <>
            <Sidebar>
                <Router>
                        <Redirect path='/user-portal' to='/user-portal/dashboard' exact />
                        <Route path='/user-portal/Dashboard' component={Dashboard} exact />
                </Router>
            </Sidebar>
        </>
    )
```

Comment: It's better if you can provide a link of Codesandbox or GitHub

Comment: if you style properly 1st code should work as `Sidebar` & `Router` components are siblings. bt in 2nd code you rendered `Router` as a child of `Sidebar`